# Problemas com asp, recuperação de valor retornado de um stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp

Boa tarde, estou tendo problemas na recuperação de uma valor retornado em uma stored procedure.
O banco de dados é sql server.

A procedure executa um insert e retorna o id desse dado, porém eu não consigo recuperar o valor do id no asp.

```
   <% sql = "exec nova '86320115000189','TESTE TESTE TESTE'"
   Set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
     rs.Open sql, conn    
       codigo_avaliacao = cInt(rs("codigo"))
     rs.Close
   Set rs=Nothing 
   %>
  <%=codigo_avaliacao%>
```

Alguém saberia me dizer se está algo errado no código ou outra maneira de fazer isso em asp.

obs: meus conhecimentos em asp são bem limitados.

Comment: Leonardo seja bem vindo ao SOpt, quando você diz *problemas*, quais seriam? Coloque na sua pergunta para que fique mais claro e assim possa conseguir uma resposta adequada ao seu problema...

Comment: Pode colocar na pergunta a estrutura da procedure? Os parametros de input e qual o retorno?

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta na função cInt, o valor era retornado na rs("codigo"), porém a função cInt não retornava nada.

Retirei essa função e funcionou perfeitamente.